# Flutter:error running pod install after upgrading to flutter facebook login v3.00

Tags: ios, flutter

I just change the flutter facebook plugin from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0 and now I am getting POD error when I execute flutter build.

Need some help how debug and fix this issue

MY POD file snippet

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'

flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.39.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.39.1'
```

--- This error message ----

This is the error dump

CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  M Flutter
  - FBSDKCoreKit
  - FBSDKLoginKit
  - file_picker
  - firebase_analytics
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core
  - firebase_crashlytics
  - firebase_dynamic_links
  - firebase_messaging
  - firebase_remote_config
  - flutter_facebook_login
  - flutter_statusbarcolor
  - google_sign_in
  - keyboard_visibility
  - location
  - package_info
  - path_provider
  - share
  - shared_preferences
  - url_launcher

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1)

  In Podfile:
    FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1)

    flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.5)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1), FBSDKLoginKit (= 4.39.1), FBSDKLoginKit (~> 5.5)` dependency were found, but
they required a higher minimum deployment target.
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install

I have clear the cache but I still get the error..

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972072/how-to-get-a-ternary-operator-to-work-inside-jsx has a *great* alternative approach, even if you figured out the conditional operator issue

Answer (score 2):

Delete

> **Podfile.lock**

Then run

> **pod install**.

It worked for me.

Am using

> flutter_facebook_login

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following in the `ios` directory:

- $ pod repo update
- $ pod install

You might need to delete the `Podfile.lock` file first (i'm not sure it helps but it's what i did).

Answer (score 0):

to fix used two commands:
- pod repo update
-  pod update FBSDKCoreKit

——————————————————————
after pod repo update  :

MacRoberto-8:Nixtelecom robertofonseca$ cd ios

MacRoberto-8:ios robertofonseca$ pod update FBSDKCoreKit

Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.3)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (5.6.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (5.6.0)
Installing firebase_core (0.0.1)
.
.
.
.
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 14 dependencies from the Podfile and 37 total pods installed.

MacRoberto-8:Nixtelecom robertofonseca$ flutter build ios --release

.
.
  === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===